# compare string A with string B if match place in column D

Tags: excel, string, replace

The strings in column B are in order and aligned with the email addresses in column C. Now, the strings in column A are not in order though they have the extra value that should be added to the belowing email address.

In other words i take the string of B1 then i search for it in column A and when found i take the extra value and add that in column D. So that i have the matching extra value that belongs to email address in column C1.

Is it possible that the software take this work out of my hands by somekind of function?

So that it takes the string of B2, searches for it in column A and when found it adds the extra value in column D. To make it easier it can add the whole string with extra value in D2. So that i have a matching strings with extra value that belongs to a certain email in C.

All help is much appcriated and before hand i wanna say thank you for taking the time to help me out here.

Comment: Clarifying question: for the string in A1, the part that should correspond to a cell from column B is the one from the beginning to ...f9  and the "extra value" is ZWIERS ?

Comment: exacta punto Kruger!

Answer (score 3):

Use INDEX/MATCH to find the match and SUBSTITUTE to remove the unwanted text.  Then use IFERROR to deal with non mathces:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1&"*",A:A,0)),B1&":",""),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Briljant, this is it! Leaving me with the question where or how do i insert the function and do i just c/p this one?

Comment: For when i just copy ur function line and add it into column D i receive an error. Can u show me through a picture please, much appreciated!

Comment: @kafka there is a picture in the answer.  depending on your local settings you may need to change all the `,` to `;`

Comment: @kafka also your picture is open office not excel so I do not know if this will work with open office.

Comment: Scott much gracias armano! Perhaps someone else knows how this function must be inserted in openoffice.

Comment: Anyone a experienced open office user who knows how to insert this excel function into open office api? Much thanks !!